# Pandas output null column

Tags: python, pandas, null

My goal is to add a column where it would display the field name(s) of the empty cell.

```
Name x  y z
abc  1    3
        0  
ijk  m    
lmn  1  2 3
```

The new column would be:

```
Name x  y z   Empty
abc  1    3     y
        0      x,Name,z
ijk  m         y,z
lmn  1  a c
```

I've tried:  pd.isnull(df).any(1).nonzero() but this only show the row that contains empty cell.

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Missing']=df.where((df=='')).stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply(','.join)
df
Out[222]: 
  Name  x  y  z   Missing
0  abc  1     3         y
1          0     Name,x,z
2  ijk  m             y,z
3  lmn  1  2  3       NaN
```

Comment: I knew stack() would involved.  However, I got this error when I apply the code: TypeError: Could not compare [''] with block values.  Do you know why?

Comment: @TylerNG  so your blank is blank or NaN

Comment: It's NaN in this case.  In Sql, it's blank but I guess when I converted it into df it becomes NaN.

Comment: @TylerNG then we change df.where((df=='')) to df.where((df.isnull()))

Comment: I did try that and it would just return NaN instead of the col names.

Comment: I also tried df['Missing']=df.where(df.isnull().any(1)) .stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply(','.join) and it gives me the opposite of what I want haha

Comment: @TylerNG ok if you have na Let us adding df=df.fillna('') before my code

Answer (score 1):

Well... this isn't a vectorized solution but it does the job. Maybe someone else will come along and have a better way. You'll have to fix the `get_null_col_name` function to check and consider `0` and `NaN` as well. But this should give you an idea.

```
>>> df
   Name     x     y     z
0   abc     1  None     3
1  None  None     0  None
2   ijk     m  None  None
3   lmn     1     a     c
>>> def get_null_col_name(row):
...     return ','.join([col for col in row.index if not row[col]])
...
>>> df['Empty'] = df.apply(get_null_col_name, axis=1)
>>> df
   Name     x     y     z       Empty
0   abc     1  None     3           y
1  None  None     0  None  Name,x,y,z
2   ijk     m  None  None         y,z
3   lmn     1     a     c       Empty
```